# discord py roles creation with permissions

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have been working on this as a side project for like 2 months and for the life of me I can not get the bot to create roles with permissions. Here is what I have.

```
levels={
        "Admin":{"name":"ADMIN","hoist":"1","colour":"0x6F0A0A","permissions":""},
    "Moderator":{"name":"WATCHMEN","hoist":"1","colour":"0xFF611A","permissions":"discord.permissions(manage_roles=True,kick_members=True,ban_members=True,create_instant_invite=True,mention_everyone=True,change_nickname=True,manage_nicknames=True,read_message_history,send_messages=True,embed_links=True,send_tts_messages,attach_files=True,external_emojis=True,add-reactions=True)"},
    "Member":{"name":"MEMBER","hoist":"0","colour":"0x52D41A","permissions":"discord.permissions(send_messages=True)"},
    "Verify":{"name":"VERIFY","hoist":"1","colour":"0xFFFFFF","permissions":"discord.permissions(send_messages=True)"},

}
```

and

```
async def cook_roles(ctx):
    for level in levels.keys():
        guild=ctx.guild
        name=levels[level]['name']
        hoist=levels[level]['hoist']
        colour=levels[level]['colour']
      #  perms=levels[level]['permissions']
        if name == "Admin":
            perms=discord.Permissions.all()
        else:
            perms=discord.Permissions(levels[level]['permissions'])
        print=(perms)
        await ctx.send(perms)
        await guild.create_role(name=name,hoist=hoist,permissions=perms,colour=discord.Colour(int(colour,16)))
```

Any help is appriciated!

I tried taking away the discord.Permissions() and formatting in perms like this

```
perms=discord.Permissions(levles[level]['permissions'])
```

but that didn't work either. (I have tried a host of things and just haven't figured it out.)

---

Here is a traceback for the first provided answer:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "ny.py", line 483, in build
    await cook_roles(ctx)
  File "ny.py", line 551, in cook_roles
    await guild.create_role(name=name,hoist=hoist,permissions=perms,colour=discord.Colour(int(colour,16)))
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

Comment: Also used the .getvalue() but no such luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string values in dict, which is not considered as real objects.

You can store any type objects in dicts, so all you need to to do, basically, is to make values in dict actual objects with actual types.

You also was trying to use `permissions` module instead of `Permissions` class. 
And always make sure that permissions names exists: [`discord.Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) *(your mistake was in some missing `=True` and `add-reactions` instead of `add_reactions`)*

```py
levels = {
    "Admin": {"name": "ADMIN", "hoist": True, "colour": 0x6F0A0A, "permissions": discord.Permissions()},
    "Moderator": {
        "name": "WATCHMEN",
        "hoist": True,
        "colour": 0xFF611A,
        "permissions": discord.Permissions(manage_roles=True,
        kick_members=True,
        ban_members=True,
        create_instant_invite=True,
        mention_everyone=True,
        change_nickname=True,
        manage_nicknames=True,
        read_message_history=True,
        send_messages=True,
        embed_links=True,
        send_tts_messages=True,
        attach_files=True,
        external_emojis=True,
        add_reactions=True),
    },
    "Member": {
        "name": "MEMBER",
        "hoist": False,
        "colour": 0x52D41A,
        "permissions": discord.Permissions(send_messages=True),
    },
    "Verify": {
        "name": "VERIFY",
        "hoist": True,
        "colour": 0xFFFFFF,
        "permissions": discord.Permissions(send_messages=True),
    },
}
```

Comment: This yields a traceback which I have included in my question now.

Comment: `int(str, base)` is required only for strings conversion, use just `discord.Colour(colour)`